# Flutter Stripe does not showing payment sheet on ios device

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to integrate a Stripe payment using flutter_stripe package. but it is throwing an error

**Error**

Unhandled Exception: StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: No payment sheet has been initialized yet, message: No payment sheet has been initialized yet, stripeErrorCode: null, declineCode: null, type: null))

(This error is showing only for ios device, but working fine on android device.)

**services.dart**

```
payNow() async {
try{
  Map<String, dynamic> stripeData = widget.paymentData;
  print("stripeData===== ${stripeData['stripeCustomerId']}");
  Stripe.publishableKey = Constants.stripeKey;
  Stripe.merchantIdentifier = Constants.merchantId;
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
    paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        paymentIntentClientSecret: stripeData['paymentIntentSecret'],
        merchantDisplayName: 'Courses',
        customerId: stripeData['stripeCustomerId'],
        customerEphemeralKeySecret: stripeData['ephemeralKey'],
        applePay: true),
  );
  await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
  widget.submitData();
} on Exception catch (e) {
  if (e is StripeException) {
    print("Error from Stripe: ${e.error.localizedMessage}");
  } else {
    print("Unforeseen error: $e");
  }
  rethrow;
}

}
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
Stripe.publishableKey = Constants.stripeKey;
Stripe.merchantIdentifier= Constants.merchantId;
Stripe.urlScheme = 'flutterstripe';
await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
runApp(MyApp());
}
```

please help me to solve this error

Comment: stripeData = widget.paymentData;  Is it coming properly from the backend?

Comment: Yes, data is coming properly

Comment: Infact, payment sheet is showing in android device but not on ios device

Comment: Try `applePay: false` to make sure that there is no hidden integration problem with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the merchantCountryCode parameter in initPaymentSheet().

Comment: That's very cool you've solved it by your own. I would suggest edit your question, or add your approach as a comment. this is the most common way and keep it clear for readers.